# Calculating electric potential from electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

> The Electric field in  a region is given as $\vec{E}=-2x\hat{i}+3y^2\hat{j}-4z^3\hat{k}$. Calculate the electric potential at point $(1,2,3)m$

Now we know that electric potential at point $A$ is defined as $$V_A=-\frac{W_{elc}}{q_0}\bigg]_{\infty\to A}$$

which evaluates to $$V_A=-\int_{\infty}^{(1,2,3)}\vec{E}.d\vec{r}$$

Now this integral evaluates to an inderteminate form $(\infty-\infty)$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I’ve come across the type of question before. For some reason, the setter wants you to assume potential to be 0 at the origin. Though they usually specify it in the question if so.

Comment: What about $\,U=x^2-y^3+z^4+\texttt{constant}\,$  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric potential at position $\vec{r}_A$ is defined to be
$$V(\vec{r}_A)=V(\vec{r}_0)
 -\int_{\vec{r}_0}^{\vec{r}_A}\vec{E}(\vec{r})\cdot d\vec{r}$$

The definition allows you to choose any $\vec{r}_0$ you like.
You have already noticed that choosing $\vec{r}_0=(\infty,\infty,\infty)$
doesn't work, because then your integral diverges.
So choose another one. I suggest to use $\vec{r}_0=\vec{0}=(0,0,0)$,
because then the integration becomes most easy.

Notice that your final result will still contain $V(\vec{0})$
as an unknown constant. But this is unavoidable.

Comment: Thankyou , but if we assign some arbitrary value to that unknown constant we can determine potential at point A, yes??

Comment: @LalitTolani Yes, you can determine it after assigning a reference potential. However, a well-posed assignment should have specified a reference potential at some point.

Comment: Thankyou for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

The lower limit on the integral for the potential is not always $\infty$. It's the position where the electric field is *zero*, that is where one "starts pushing against it" so as so to do work, which then becomes energy stored in the potential.

Physically, charges and currents are localised, which give you (physical) boundary conditions $|\mathbf{E}| \rightarrow 0$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$, hence why $\infty$ is usually taken as the "starting" point (e.g. for a point charge).

In this case, the electric field is $0$ at $r = (0,0,0)$, so you should start the integration there.

Comment: *The lower limit on the integral for the potential is not always ∞. It's the position where the electric field is zero,*  - Not so!  The position of the zero of potential can be anywhere one chooses.  In this problem it might well be that the origin of the coordinate system was that chosen position.

Comment: Ok but why is that the lower limit is taken the position where electric field is zero?

Comment: @Farcher Yes , I also think same , here I assumed potential to be 0 at infinity and then solved it

Comment: *why is that the lower limit is taken the position where electric field is zero?* One can only suggest is that is where the setter of the question decided the zero of potential should be but failed to tell anyone else otherwise there should be a (unknown) constant term in the answer.

Comment: The assumption in the definition of the potential (energy), is that it is the work done in assembling a system of charges. So you bring "in" your second charge, and then start moving it to the final, desired, position. The act of getting a new charge from whatever external reservoir should not cost any energy, hence why it is assumed that it is placed in a place of zero *field*. The zero of the *potential* can be wherever you want, by virtue of this being a gauge and hence physically insensitive to an offset. But it will have a *minimum* at $0$ because its derivative $E$ is $0$ there.

Comment: Potential energy and potential are not the same thing and in this problem you are asked about the potential.  The fact that the potential is a minimum at a particular position does not necessarily define the position of the zero of potential.

Comment: They are the same thing barring a factor of $q$ (charge) which is not gonna solve the infinity problem. I never talked about the zero of the *potential*. But zero of the *field*. That is, where you place the charge to being with before doing work on it.